# How does 'forall' affect function signature?

Tags: function, haskell, signature, parametric-polymorphism

I declared two functions using the 'forall' quantifier. The first of them has a quantifier with all generic type parameters before the signature. The second has quantifiers in place of the first usage of each generic type parameter.

```
f :: forall a b c. a -> b -> c -> b -> a
f a _ _ _ = a

g :: forall a. a ->
     forall b. b ->
     forall c. c -> b -> a
g a _ _ _ = a
```

I expected that these two functions would be the same (The difference is only in the style of description), but the following two tests showed me that it is not.

```
w_f :: (forall a b c. a -> b -> c -> b -> a) -> Bool
w_f _ = True

w_g :: (forall a. a ->
        forall b. b ->
        forall c. c -> b -> a) -> Bool
w_g _ = True
```

```
> w_f g
```

```
 error:  
    • Couldn't match type: forall b1. b1 -> forall c1. c1 -> b1 -> a  
                     with: b -> c -> b -> a   
      Expected: a -> b -> c -> b -> a  
      Actual: a -> forall b. b -> forall c. c -> b -> a  
    • In the first argument of ‘w_f’, namely ‘g’  
      In the expression: w_f g  
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = w_f g
```

```
> w_g f
```

```
 error:
    • Couldn't match type: b0 -> c0 -> b0 -> a
                     with: forall b. b -> forall c. c -> b -> a
      Expected: a -> forall b. b -> forall c. c -> b -> a   
        Actual: a -> b0 -> c0 -> b0 -> a  
    • In the first argument of ‘w_g’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: w_g f
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = w_g f
```

I created a graphical representation of this case to see what is wrong, but I can't.

[image]

Why are they not equivalent? Why can't we move all quantifiers out of the signature like move common multiples out of expression in math? Could somebody please provide an example of types mismatching?

Comment: The key word here is _hoisting_: quantifiers as in `A -> forall t. B` can be hoisted to obtain `forall t. A -> B` (if `t` is not in `A`). These are distinct but isomorphic types. I might recall wrongly, but I believe GHC used to do automatic hoisting in the past, but it became harder with new type extensions, so it was limited in some way (?). I can't find more details, though.

Comment: Also note that, perhaps confusingly, eta-expanding to `w_f (\x y z w -> g x y z w)` type checks, since the eta-expansion allows GHC to move the implicit type arguments around. It might be interesting to look at the generated Core and observe the type arguments `\ @a ...` being explicitly taken as input and passed as arguments, so to realize that `w_f (\x y z w -> g x y z w)` is compiled to something not quite like `g` -- the handling of the type arguments is different.

Comment: They should be equivalent if you turn on the `DeepSubsumption` extension. The explanation for why that isn't the default any more is in the simplify subsumption proposal: https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0287-simplify-subsumption.rst

Comment: @Noughtmare That looks like the skeleton of an answer to me! Just copy in one or two choice quotes from your links.

Answer (score 1):

A `forall` specifies a certain kind of function, just like `->` does.

```
f :: forall (a :: Type). a -> a 
-- "f is a function from types to (functions from values of the type passed as argument to values of that same type)"
f {- @a -} (x :: a) = x
-- "f of a type a and a value (x :: a) is x"
-- syntax for type abstractions is not present in GHC (yet!) for historical reasons
-- but they do appear in the high-level IR (pass -ddump-simpl to GHC)

main = print (f @Integer 5)
-- f must be applied to a type and then a value
-- type abstraction (@a above) and application (@Integer here) can be left unwritten
-- then GHC will infer them
```

Swapping instances of `->` (e.g. `A -> B -> C` to `B -> A -> C`)

- creates a different type, so a value of the swapped type is not acceptable for the original type, yet
- does not *meaningfully* change the type; the two types are *interconvertible*, just not implicitly.

In your very own words, "the difference is only in the style of description". Yet you're still required to be consistent about that style (i.e. the argument order). You surely aren't confused by the following:

```
data A = A; data A' = A'; data B = B; data B' = B'; data C = C
f :: A -> B -> A' -> B' -> C
f A B A' B' = C
g :: A -> A' -> B -> B' -> C
g A A' B B' = C

w_f :: (A -> B -> A' -> B' -> C) -> Bool
w_f _ = True

w_g :: (A -> A' -> B -> B' -> C) -> Bool
w_g _ = True

main = do
  print (w_f f)
  -- print (w_f g) -- error...
  print (w_f (\x y -> g y x)) -- ...must shuffle arguments
  -- print (w_g f) -- error...
  print (w_g (\x y -> f y x)) -- ...must shuffle arguments
  print (w_g g)
```

Compare:

```
-- replacing:
-- A  -> Type (named a)
-- B  -> Type (named b)
-- A' -> a
-- B' -> b
f :: forall (a :: Type) (b :: Type). a -> b -> C
f {- @_ @_ -} _ _ = C
g :: forall (a :: Type). a -> forall (b :: Type). b -> C
g {- @_ -} _ {- @_ -} _ = C
-- notice that f and g even have different equations

w_f :: (forall (a :: Type) (b :: Type). a -> b -> C) -> Bool
w_f _ = True

w_g :: (forall (a :: Type). a -> forall (b :: Type). b -> C) -> Bool
w_g _ = True

main = do
  print (w_f f)
  -- print (w_f g) -- error...
  print (w_f (\x y -> g x y)) -- ...must (invisibly) shuffle arguments
  -- print (w_g f) -- error...
  print (w_g (\x y -> f x y)) -- ...must (invisibly) shuffle arguments
  print (w_g g)
```

Your code is a slightly more elaborate version of the above. The underlying reason for the errors is the same in all three cases, and is very simple. You defined `f` and `g` with certain argument orders; you had better use them with those argument orders.

---

P.S. The comments note there's `DeepSubsumption` extension that makes `w_f g` and `w_g f` compile, and historically this behavior was the default (hence why you may have absorbed the belief that order shouldn't matter for `forall`). One reason this is no longer the default is that while there's an obvious conversion from `forall a b. a -> b -> C` to `forall a. a -> forall b. b -> C`, this conversion changes definedness.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeepSubsumption #-}
convert :: (forall a b. a -> b -> C) -> (forall a. a -> forall b. b -> C)
convert f = f

main = do
  -- print (undefined `seq` ())      -- would die with an exception
  print (convert undefined `seq` ()) -- does NOT die with an exception
  -- so... convert undefined /= undefined...
  -- even though it looks like I defined convert f = f...
  -- gross
```

GHC has thus moved towards forcing you to make it explicit when you're changing the `forall` order of a function.

Comment: RE the note at the bottom: "changes definedness" here means "changes semantics" or more concretely "changes the machine instructions that GHC emits". It can prevent sharing which could make your program much slower. Richard Eisenberg shows some concrete examples of that slowdown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMnXbBRg-B0